# Can't fetch the ledger time from DAML ledger through the JSON API

Tags: daml

I see the following error when trying to fetch the ledger time via the JSON API:

```
UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: 

com.digitalasset.ledger.api.v1.testing.TimeService/GetTime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The availability of the `TimeService` depends on the ledger implementations. If you are using the sandbox, the `TimeService` is only available if you start it in static time (i.e. time advances only via the `TimeService`) but not when you're running it in wall-clock time.

As of version 0.13.41 of the SDK, the sandbox starts in static time by default and you have to explicitly start it with the `-w` flag to run it in wall clock time, regardless of whether you start it with `daml sandbox` or with `daml start`.

Please note that the `TestService` is meant to be used exclusively for testing and demos, in any other case the returned value is not particularly useful for you.

Comment: can you please give example or the links related to this solution for getting some clarity

Comment: Running `daml sandbox --help` will give you a detailed description of all CLI parameters.